# Generate data for jQuery GanttView from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, gantt-chart

I use [jQuery GanttView](https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView) after seeing [example data](https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView/blob/master/example/data.js)

I try to generate Gantt data from PHP:

```
foreach ($activity as $key => $activity):
        $data[$key]['id'] = $activity->id;
        $data[$key]['name'] = $activity->name;
        foreach($activity->task as $key2 => $task):

            $data[$key]['series'][$key2]['name'] = $task->name;
            $data[$key]['series'][$key2]['start']  =  date( 'D M d Y H:i:s',strtotime($task->start_time)).' GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)';
            $data[$key]['series'][$key2]['end']  = date( 'D M d Y H:i:s',strtotime($task->stop_time)).' GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)';
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
```

The error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this jQuery library depends in date.js (its source can be found in [jquery.ganttView
 repo](https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView/tree/master/lib)). Function `compareTo()` comes from [date.js](https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView/blob/master/lib/date.js), so just include this script on your page.